# Retrieve only the sub document element in an object array in MongoDB collection in laravel

Tags: php, mongodb, laravel, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

Consider the following collection,

```
 {
      "_id": ObjectId("545c535e75de3e630c8b4567"),

        "tables" : [
                {
                    "_id" : ObjectId("54584f5975de3e040fe97319"),
                    "title" : "001",
                },
                {
                    "_id" : ObjectId("54584fb175de3e1c0fe97319"),
                    "title" : "002",
                }
        ]
 }
```

I need to retrieve data from this collection where tables.title = "001". I used laravel framework. I tried following codes, but not properly worked. If someone have an idea to solve this please help me.

```
DB::connection($this->connection)->collection($this->collection)->where('tables','elemMatch',array('title'=>"001"))->get();

DB::connection($this->connection)->collection($this->collection)->where('tables.title',"001")->get();

DB::connection($this->connection)->collection($this->collection)->where('tables.$.title',"001")->get();
```

Comment: I don't know about laravel framework but mongo aggregation query solve your problem.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For "singular" matches, you should just be able to just use projections:

```
$result = DB::collection('collection')->where(
    'tables.title', '001'
)->project(array( 'tables.$' => 1 ) )->get();
```

For multiple matches, you are going to need access to the "raw" driver objects in order to "filter" the array contents as you need the aggregation framework to do so. You can do it like this:

```
# Returns the original Mongo Result
$result = DB::collection('collection')->raw(function($collection)
{
    return $collection->aggregate(array(
        # Match the documents containing the matching elements first
        array(
            '$match' => array( 'tables.title' => '001' )
        ),

        # Unwind the array to "de-normalize"
        array( '$unwind' => '$tables' ),


        # Match again to "filter" the now "de-normalized" documents
        array(
            '$match' => array( 'tables.title' => '001' )
        ),

        # Construct back as an array
        array(
            '$group' => array(
                '_id' => '$_id',
                'tables' => array(
                    '$push' => '$tables'
                )
            )
        )   
    ));
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Following aggregation may solve your problem,

```
db.collectionName.aggregate({"$unwind":"$tables"},{"$project":{"title":"$tables.title","id":"$tables._id","_id":0}},{"$match":{"title":"001"}})
```

This return title and id of matching title

Comment: Thank you. I tried it. but how does it implement in laravel?